# MySQL update error #1064

Tags: mysql

This is the error:

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case='nominative' WHERE id='42'' at line 1**

This is the query:

```
UPDATE `ruen_kw` SET case='nominative' WHERE id='42'
```

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ruen_kw` (
  `id` tinyint(6) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `language` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(80) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  `translation` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `case` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `tense` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `number` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `definition` varchar(200) character set utf8 NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `keyword_2` (`keyword`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=46 ;
```

The line to be updated:

INSERT INTO `ruen_kw` (`id`, `language`, `keyword`, `translation`, `case`, `tense`, `gender`, `number`, `definition`) VALUES
(42, 'ru', 'Ñ…Ð¾Ð·ÑÐ¹ÐºÐ°', 'hostess', 'nom', '', '', '', '');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"case" is a reserved word in MySQL.  From the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html):

> Reserved words are permitted as identifiers if you quote them as
>   described in Section 9.2, “Schema Object Names”:

Try this, instead:

```
 UPDATE ruen_kw SET `case`='nominative' WHERE id='42';
```

Comment: Thanks, i just changed the name completely, but using the quotes around case didn't work.